# Python & MySQL: Matching element from list of with a record from database

Tags: python, mysql

I have a list of objects which I built with a class, and one of the properties of this class is the variable "tag". (below called tagList)

I am trying to match this variable from a record that is bought in using MySQLdb. (below called record)

I can output both to the screen, and see them identically by eye, although cannot get any if statement to match them.

I have tried several approaches, such as:

```
if str(tagList[i].tag)[2:6] is record[2]:

if str(tagList[i].tag)[2:6] is str(record[2]):
```

and other similar things. ([2:6] just to remove the ['  '] from the list element.  Printing these variables to the screen does show they are in the correct format, and I must be doing something stupid!

Still new to both Python and MySQL so would appreciate any advice!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `==` instead of `is`.

```
>>> 'abcdefgh'[2:6] is 'cdef'
False
>>> 'abcdefgh'[2:6] == 'cdef'
True
```

**Related Question**

- [Python '==' vs 'is' comparing strings, 'is' fails sometimes, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/python-vs-is-comparing-strings-is-fails-sometimes-why)

Comment: How did I make that mistake? Eugh. Sorry to waste your time!

Thanks a lot.